# Django DateInput placholder

Tags: python, django, forms

I am new to django and I have problem with showing my DateInput form. I want to use placholder in my DateInput, but its not working. Let me show you my code.

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
my_date_field = forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={"type":"date", 'placeholder': 'Select a date',
                                                                      'required': 'required'}), label='Date')
```

form.html

```
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Prva</title></head><body><form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<button type="submit">Submit</button></form></body></html>
```

I get this result
[image]

And one more question, is there any way to make only year select DateInput.

Comment: Are you using some kind of javascript on the form? That doesn't look like a default date field.

Answer (score 1):

An input element with a date type cannot store a string like "Select a date" as a placeholder. You may need to use a custom component to achieve that.